# Can't customize the _URL in flowers_tf_lite.ipynb colab

Tags: java, python

I'm using this [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/community/en/flowers_tf_lite.ipynb#scrollTo=xxL2mjVVGIrV) to retrain a classification image model with my own data hosted on google drive.
But apparently there is a issue with URL. it just say 8192/Unknown - 0s 0us/step. I have impression that it doesn't arrive to download data via the link. Help me please. Excuse me for bad english

The code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

import os

_URL = "https://drive.google.com/uc? 
 export=download&confirm=IbID&id=1cyPjY_wPxFpt7cO8Q1EaeexNzLzpTtpD"

 zip_file = tf.keras.utils.get_file(origin=_URL, 
                               fname="panel.tgz", 
                               extract=True)

base_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(zip_file), 'panel')
```

The result:

```
Downloading data from https://drive.google.com/uc? 
export=download&confirm=IbID&id=1cyPjY_wPxFpt7cO8Q1EaeexNzLzpTtpD
8192/Unknown - 0s 0us/step
```

Answer (score 0):

This URL can't download. It is Cloud file link.  In your case, the test file should be upload in FTP.